# Copying fields with clone() vs copy constructor Java

Tags: java, clone, copy-constructor

I recently started a course on Java programming language. Going through the lectures, I found these two slides that are confusing me:

1.

> If the class has a copy constructor, clone() can use the copy constructor
>   to create and return a copy of the object.

```
public Sale(Sale obj) {
        this.itemName = new String(obj.itemName);
        this.itemPrice = obj.itemPrice;
}
public Sale clone() {
        return new Sale(this);
}
```

2.

> Even though the copy constructor and clone() do the same thing (when
>   implemented like shown previously), in certain situations only clone()
>   can work

This is the example shown (Sale and DiscountSale are implemented elsewhere):

```
public class CopyTest {

    public static Sale[] badCopy(Sale[] a) {
        Sale[] b = new Sale[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            b[i] = new Sale(a[i]);
        return b;
    }

    public static Sale[] goodCopy(Sale[] a) {
        Sale[] b = new Sale[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            b[i] = a[i].clone();
        return b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sale[] a = new Sale[2];
        a[0] = new Sale("atomic coffee mug", 130.00);
        a[1] = new DiscountSale("invisible paint", 5.00, 10);
        int i;

        Sale[] b = badCopy(a);

        System.out.println("With copy constructors: ");
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("a[" + i + "] = " + a[i]);
            System.out.println("b[" + i + "] = " + b[i]);
        }

        b = goodCopy(a);

        System.out.println("With clone(): ");
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("a[" + i + "] = " + a[i]);
            System.out.println("b[" + i + "] = " + b[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

What is the difference between the copy constructor and clone(), when clone() uses the copy constructor in its implementation? Why would only one work properly?

Comment: http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/01/which-is-better-option-cloning-or-copy-constructors.html&ei=-bG4btW3&lc=en-IN&geid=7&s=1&m=189&ts=1444490840&sig=APONPFm03Ou7iPhfk4cOcn7XrAERPiLLLA

Comment: That all seems wrong, e.g. why create a new `String` in the copy constructor when strings are immutable, and I can't think of a condition that would work with `clone()` and couldn't be done in a copy constructor, however there are cases where `clone()` don't work. Where did you find this?

Comment: @Andreas I changed the copy constructor to create a new String just to be sure it works, as I am new to Java. The rest was from the course materials.

Comment: Copy costructor can't be used for deep cloning when type of some property is an interface or abstract class.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to go with copy constructors as long as the composed objects does not have any inheritance hierarchy.

Clone does not call constructor. Prefer clone when you have complex hierarchy of object composition. If not, stick to copy constructor.

Comment: Even with inheritance, your statement is good, because either way, the superclass must implement copy constructor or `clone()`.